# (React-Native) Item in Flatlist do not shows the correct style as in Stylesheet on the first load

Tags: android, css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a view with a top card showing an image and a bottom card showing relative information in a horizontal flatlist.

The style gets broken on the first load and as soon as I refresh the code without any change, the component shows the correct style as expected.

This is happening after I migrated the react native from 0.60.5 to 0.61.0.

This is the code for component.

```
<View
        accessible={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? false : true}
        style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
          <View style={styles.topContainer}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={{uri: item.img, cache: 'default'}}
              resizeMode="contain"
              imageStyle={{borderRadius: 4}}
              style={styles.topContainer}>
            </ImageBackground>
            <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.destination}>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.description}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

This is the stylesheet.

```
import {StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';
import Color from '../../../../utilities/Color';
import {BaseStyle} from '../../../../utilities/Style';

const flex1 = {
  flex: 1,
};

const flexRow = {
  flexDirection: 'row',
};

const centerView = {
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
};

const cardStyle = {
  ...Platform.select({
    ios: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: Color.white,
      shadowOffset: {width: 1, height: 1},
      shadowOpacity: 0.2,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      borderRadius: 2,
      shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
    },
    android: {
      elevation: 2,
      borderRadius: 2,
    },
  }),
};

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...flex1,
    padding: 16,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#efefef',
  },
  title: {
    ...BaseStyle.font16RobotoBoldGray,
  },
  subtitle: {
    ...BaseStyle.textSubHead1,
    top: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    color: Color.lightTextGray,
  },
});      
export const ItemStyle = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        ...flex1,
        marginBottom: 15,
      },
      itemContainer: {
        height: 210,
        width: 260,
        marginRight: 15,
      },
      topContainer: {
        height: 162,
        borderRadius: 4,
      },
      bottomContainer: {
        ...cardStyle,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 120,
        marginHorizontal: 8,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        borderRadius: 4,
        backgroundColor: Color.white,
      },
      destination: {
        ...BaseStyle.textTitle,
        fontSize: 14,
        lineHeight: 18,
        color: Color.darkGray,
        marginBottom: 8,
      },
      subHeading: {
        marginBottom: 4,
      },
      caption: {
        ...BaseStyle.textCaption,
        color: Color.lightTextGray,
      },
      subtitle: {
        ...BaseStyle.textSubHead1,
      },
    });
```

This is the image at the first load
[image: Error in component style]

This is the image after I refresh the code.
[image: Correct style component]

Please suggest a way, how can I debug it. Or something wrong I am doing in my stylesheet?

Comment: at first add styles directly in view item and test again

Comment: @MeisamSaba Thanks for responding. I have checked to add styles directly in the view item. The issue remains the same. Any other clue?

Comment: did you check screen in release and have same problem?

Comment: Yes, the same problem in the release build too.

Comment: @MeisamSaba I am now able to fix it by removing all the borderRadius from the stylesheet. But not able to understand if this is the real cause of the problem. After removing all borderRadius , the UI of the component is properly rendered. Please let me know if you are able to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all the borderRadius solved it.